# Why can't I get csspie to work?

Tags: internet-explorer, rounded-corners, css, css3pie

I have a div that I want to display as a small colored circle. I added rounded corners using the border-radius property, which of course works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, and even IE9, but not earlier versions of IE. I am trying to use [CSSPIE](http://css3pie.com/) to render the rounded corners in earlier versions of IE. I downloaded PIE.htc and saved it in my css folder.

This is the gist of my css:

```
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background-color: red;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

However, the div is still displaying in IE7 and 8 as a red square instead of a circle. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Path issue?

<s>Replace:</s>

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

With:

```
behavior: url("PIE.htc");
```

**Edit**

From the [docs](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths):

> IE interprets the URL for the behavior property relative to the source
>   HTML document, rather than relative to the CSS file like every other
>   CSS property. This makes invoking the PIE behavior inconvenient,
>   because the URL has to either be:
>
> ```
> 1. Absolute from the domain root — this makes the CSS not easily moveable between directories — or,
> 2. Relative to the HTML document — this makes the CSS not easily reusable between different HTML files.
> ```

Change your path to be relative to the HTML file rather than relative to the css file.

Comment: The docs don't seem to indicate a need for quotation marks: http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/ . I did try following your suggestion, though, and it didn't help :(

Comment: Where is the `.htc` in your folder?

Comment: directly in the same folder as the css file

Comment: One directory up... thank you! I changed the path to url(/css/PIE.htc) so that it's relative to the html file and it's now working!

Comment: the way it is now is not really correct - it's not the quotes that fixed it. I'll edit your answer and then accept it